# Sending Text data to sound card in c#

Tags: text, wave

I want to send text data to sound card like "my name is alex"?
how can i do this? do i have to convert it to .wav first? if yes then how to convert text to wav file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built [SpeechSynthesis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in C# 4.0

```
using(var tts = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer())
{
   tts.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
   tts.Speak("Hello");

   tts.SetOutputToWaveFile("myHello.wav");
   tts.Speak("Hello Again");
}
```

In a webbrowser you could use Google's text2speech (translate really):

http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=HelloWorld&tl=en

Comment: i need to save that speech to a .wav file also